# Best motherboard power supply combo for backblaze server

Tags: backup, configuration, hardware

Building a backblaze server as described in this article.

http://blog.backblaze.com/

So 45 hard drives in one box. I'm making it a MSDPM 2010 server so I actually don't even need raid cards in there as MSDPM will figure out how to use all of the hard drives on it's own.

So need to know what motherboard, CPU, power supply I should get.

Primary hard drive : SSD 128GB Storage : 45 1.5GB sata drives OS : windows 2008 Backup software : Microsoft System center Data protection server 2010

Need to know Which mother board to buy which will support 45 SATA hard drives. Don't need a raid card. Which power supply can power all 45 hard drives, 1 ssd drive, motherboard.

Best set of equipment that meets my needs wins

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the site blog and their "pod" design, any motherboard that can support *at least* 4 SATA cards should do. You didn't even mention what type of CPU you would use or how much RAM but assuming you're following the same recipe as Backblaze has given, I don't think it really matters much. Get a reputable, solid motherboard, any CPU and solid RAM and you should be fine. I can't speak to a specific one, however in terms of power supply, I would suggest brands such as Corsair, Antec or PC Power & Cooling. Don't skimp on the power supply.

But you know you could just *read* the article and see Appendix A for a list of the parts they used and start from there.

> 760 Watt Power Supply Zippy PSM-5760
>   760 Watt Power Supply with Custom
>   Wiring (qtys of 200+)
>
> Intel E8600 Wolfdale 3.33 GHz LGA 775
>   65W Dual-Core Processor
>
> Intel BOXDG43NB LGA 775 G43 ATX
>   Motherboard

Answer (score 0):

The raid cards are needed simply because they give you more sata ports to use.  You need 9 total sata cables to go to the various sata backplains.  From there you will need to have one extra to run your SSD drive.